# Ports can't be used even though nothing is on them

Tags: windows-10, networking, firewall, port

My Windows 10 computer keeps getting stuck in a state where many ports are unable to be used, but when I try to find and kill whatever is using the port I can't find anything. Restarting my computer fixes the problem and frees up the port but eventually the problem always comes back. Right now it is happening on port 3000, I get these errors when I try running anything on it like a web server in Python or ExpressJS:

`python -m http.server 3000`

```
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

`node app.js`

```
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:3000
code: 'EACCES',
errno: -4092,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '0.0.0.0',
port: 3000
```

But it's not just port 3000. The following snippet fails on every port from 3000 to 3166 (then successfully runs on 3167)

```
for ((i=3000;i<=4000;i++)); do
    python -m http.server 3000
done
```

I run into the same problem on many different ports and can only ever fix it by restarting my computer, another example is PyCharm fails to start giving the error `java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind` when trying to bind on any port between 6942 and 6991.

How can I figure out what is causing my ports to stop working and fix this?

Here's what I've tried so far:

- `netstat -ano | findStr "3000"` returns nothing
- `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange | findStr "3000"` returns nothing
- PowerShell `Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 3000` returns `No MSFT_NetTCPConnection objects found with property 'LocalPort' equal to '3000'`
- `resmon.exe` shows nothing on port 3000 under `Listening Ports` or `TCP Connections`
- `TCPView` shows nothing on port 3000
- Checked if the port was open using [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19196218/3620725)
- Disabled both Windows Defender Real-time protection & Firewalls (and I have no other antivirus software)
- Browsing through `Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall -> Advanced Settings` there are only items with `Allow` under the `Action` column
- Used Wireshark to watch for any TCP activity on ports 3000-3126, didn't see anything
- Scanned my computer with Malwarebytes, Kaspersky, ESET, HitmanPro

I'm at a loss here, can't think of anything else short of reinstalling Windows 10. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like the port is in use, but some permission problem. Did you try to run it as Administrator?

Comment: @golimar I had Git Bash and cmd running as administrator for all the actions listed in my post. I just confirmed in Python, `ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()` returns `1`. And I did check the Windows Firewall but saw nothing blocked, any idea where else I could see port permission settings?

Comment: Oh I found it! `netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp` shows me many exclusion ranges including 2927-3126, so this seems to be what's causing my problems. Still wondering how I can figure out what is adding these exclusions?

Comment: Fixed it with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478869/cannot-bind-to-some-ports-due-to-permission-denied/62359555#62359555

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62359555/3620725

`netsh int ipv4 set dynamic tcp start=49152 num=16384`